# How do you edit an APK file so the app won't show ads?

Tags: apk, ads

It's one of those thoughts you have just before nodding off to sleep. How would I do this?

Comment: The practical answer is that you don't edit the APK file (which is actually a ZIP file) because it's not that simple, but find another way to block the [tag:ads]. However, our sister site [reverseengineering.se] may help more in this field.

Comment: It is usually easier to just prevent loading of the ads, e.g. using a local VPN like https://blokada.org

Comment: You can also try a `Pi Hole` to block ads.

Answer (score 1):

You can try finding the mod apk online. If you are into coding, then you can try using java decompiler to decompile the apk and see the source code. If you are lucky enough to find the exact place of where Ads being placed in code, then you can modify as per your requirement. However, now a days, it is very difficult to decompile into straight original source code due to increased security. For learning purposes, I used to use Apk-Studio for decompiling, making changes and then compiling again with modified code/resources.